# ¿Cómo arrancar sonarqube?

Tags: java, c#, sonar

Buenas tardes comunidad, estoy investigando un poco sobre la herramienta SonarQube, pero estoy teniendo unos problemas, según la documentación en la página de ellos, para correr el servicio, sólo hay que descomprimir los archivos descargados y correr el .bat desde el cmd, pero a mi me da este error:

```
C:\Users\danie>C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Unable to locate the class org.sonar.application.App: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:    org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
jvm 1    |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class} [app_arguments]
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Where:
jvm 1    |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
jvm 1    |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
jvm 1    |                   application.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Presione cualquier tecla para continuar . . .
```

No sé si lleva alguna configuración antes de poder usarla.

En la documentación no dice nada.

Gracias.

Comment: Que versión de Java tienes instalada?

Comment: tuve muchos problemas con Sonarqube, hasta que vi este vídeo, es extremadamente preciso, espero te sirva: "Videotutorial: Auditorías de código con SonarQube"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur_qsRPfi3E&list=PL_ZKDvawKL4IjI02a6aWfONmSwsx9wBRN&index=1&t=587s !Saludos¡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por este error :

> org/sonar/application/App : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

se puede determinar que estas usando una versión incorrecta de Java, [SonarQube 6.7.1 tiene como requerimiento Java 8](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements), instalalo y debe funcionar sin problema.

Además hay que modificar el archivo `wrapper.conf` para definir la nueva ruta de Java:

```
wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
```

Comment: Ya lo instalé y modifiqué el archivo wrapper con la ruta. pero ahora me tira un error que dice: Error al ejecutar el programa 'StartSonar.bat': El ejecutable especificado no es una aplicación válida para esta plataforma de sistema operativo

Comment: "El ejecutable especificado no es una aplicación válida ara esta plataforma de sistema operativo" , estas usando windows de 32 bits?

Comment: No, es de 64 bits

Comment: que obtienes si ejecutas desde linea de comandos : wmic os get osarchitecture

Comment: OSArchitecture 64 bits

Comment: Veo que ejecutas el archivo C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-xx\StartSonar.bat ! Sera que necesitas reiniciar para que tome algunos cambios que realizo al actualizar java :|